# Error en el estilo del menú fijo jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, css3

Tengo un menú creado con css y jQuery esta conformado con dos div: el primer div va a contener número de contacto y otros, el segundo div va a contener el menú de navegación.

El segundo div va a ser el div fijo, hasta aquí lo he logrado bien pero no me agrada mucho al bajar porque tiene un estilo como si se trancara.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 40) $('#menu').addClass("fixed").fadeIn();
    else $('#menu').removeClass("fixed");
  });
});
```

```css
#menu {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  height: 72px;
  width: 1349px;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  z-index: 10000;
}

#area {
  height: 800px;
}

#nav {
  height: 24px;
  width: 1349px;
  background: #fbfbfb url(../img/grad.png) center top repeat-x;
  padding: 6px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-user {
  float: right;
  padding: 10px 210px 0px 10px;
}

.shop-phone {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 0px 0px 80px;
  line-height: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
  <div id="nav">
    <div class="shop-phone"><i class="icon-phone2"></i> 0123-456-789</div>
    <div class="nav-user">
      <!--<a href="cart.php"><i class="icon-cart"></i><span class="badge">0</span></a>-->Iniciar sesión</div>
  </div>
  <div id="menu">

  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="slider-container">
      <ul id="slider" class="slider-wrapper">
        <li class="slide-current"><img src=""></li>
        <li><img src=""></li>
      </ul>
      <ul></ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="area">

</div>
<div id="footer">
  <div id="footer-menu">
    <div class="list-col-1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Aquí el link del código y el ejemplo funcionando https://jsfiddle.net/3dxmfejn/

Quiero eliminar ese pequeño detalle que sucede al bajar o al hacer el scroll, ese pequeño defecto que se ve como si se trancara.

Quiero lograr hacer el menú como el diseño de esta pagina este es el link http://www.global-seo.es/ si pueden observar el segundo div baja pero el efecto o la animación es muy diferente a mi diseño.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

si quieres conseguir el mismo efecto te aconsejaría plantearlo de otra forma, en vez de añadir 'fixed' tendrías que englobar el menu y el nav en un mismo elemento con la posición 'fixed'. Para la animación al hacer scroll modifica la propiedad top equivalente a la altura de 'nav'.

Si te fijas en el codigo de la pagina, es precisamente lo que hacen. Espero que ter haya servido :)

En cuanto al js :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 40){
         $('#menu').addClass("fixed"); // intenta evitar busquedas en el 
                                       // dom en una funcion como scroll 
    }else{
         $('#menu').removeClass("fixed");
    }
  });
});

 $(document).ready(function(){
 var menu = $('#menu');
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 40){
         menu.addClass("fixed"); // esto es mucho mas rapido, ya que 
                                 // tienes la referencia y no hara la 
                                 // busqueda por todo el dom cada vez que haces scroll
    }else{
         menu.removeClass("fixed");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Gracias amigo por responder, pero no entiendo a que te refieres con plantearlo diferente puede publicar el ejemplo que indicas o editar el codigo tal como me recomiendas en el siguiente enlace [https://jsfiddle.net/3dxmfejn/](https://jsfiddle.net/3dxmfejn/) ante mano te agradezco.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/g8mnpLqn/

Comment: amigo el código editado no funciona debe desaparecer enseguida el primer div que contiene los datos de contactos y al subir no aparece el primer div que contiene los datos de contactos demoran un par de segundos para que aparezca no es igual no asimila al estilo de este pagina [http://www.global-seo.es/](http://www.global-seo.es/) si puedes observar al momento de bajar solo el segundo div queda como el menú fijo y los datos muestran enseguida es todo lo contrario al diseño que has implementado se demora en aparecer los datos.

Comment: Vale lo acabo de revisar, no tuve en cuanta la asyncronia del animate. Te paso lo que si que funciona https://jsbin.com/ladohawime/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: perfecto amigo gracias, ahora edita la respuesta para así poder seleccionar como resuelta vale.